# Zf2 - Set value in element inside collection

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a collection used in form, i know that if i want to set a value in a normal element i use:

```
$form->get('submit')->setValue('Update');
```

How can i set a value in the field 'Address "For example"' in a collection '' "I use zend Framework 2".

```
$companies = $this->getCompaniesTable()->getCompanies($id);
$form = new CompaniesForm();
$form->bind($companies);
$form->get('submit')->setValue('Update');
$form->get('submit')->setValue('Update');
$form->get('address')->setValue('test address');
```

Last line of the prev. code doesn't work, what's wrong ?!

The form code is:

```
<?php

namespace Companies\Form;

//use Zend\Form\Element;
use Zend\Form\Form;

class CompaniesForm extends Form {

    public function __construct($name = null) {
        parent::__construct('companies');
        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
        $this->setAttribute('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'type' => 'Hidden'
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'type' => 'Text'
        ));

        // address field
        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
            'name' => 'address',
            'options' => array(
                'count' => 1,
                'should_create_template' => false,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'template_placeholder' => '__placeholder__',
                'target_element' => array(
                    'type' => 'Companies\Form\AddressFieldset'
                )
            ),
        ));
        // address field

        // email field
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'email',
            'type' => 'text',
            'options' => array('label' => 'Email:'),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'type' => 'Submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'value' => 'Go',
                'id' => 'submitbutton'
            )
        ));
    }

}
```

The addressFieldset file:

```
<?php

namespace Companies\Form;

use Companies\Entity\Address;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;
use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods as ClassMethodsHydrator;

class AddressField {

    /**
     * @var string
      \ */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @return Address
      \ */
    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
      \ */
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

}

class AddressFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('Address');
        $this->setHydrator(new ClassMethodsHydrator(false))->setObject(new AddressField());

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Address: '
            )
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return array
      \ */
    public function getInputFilterSpecification() {
        return array(
            'name' => array(
                //'required' => true,
            )
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: Unable to answer without you proving your form code.

Comment: I added a form code in the post above.

Comment: And what EXACTLY do you want to change? ;) A certain value on one of the Phone-Fieldsets? thi is kinda important ^^

Comment: It's AddressFieldset not TelephoneFieldset "my wrong here", So i want to change one of the addresses fields.

Comment: The Question is what purpose exactly? A collection is an array of Fieldsets in this case. So if you want to change the value you'll need to change the fieldset. Changing a single value of ONE of the MULTIPLE rendered fieldsets is kinda bad (huge design-flaw then).

Comment: The purpose only to show the address from db on the company "edit form - address input textbox", addresses is in the separated db table.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41969/discussion-between-ahmad-soliman-and-sam)

Answer (score 7):

You need to take collection as element from your form and you get list of field sets of your collection. 
In you view:

```
$collection = $form->get('address');
$fieldSets = $collection->getFieldsets();

// In your example you use one element as field set count = 1
// I guess you want to change field named address in your collection of the same name

$address = $fieldSets[0]->get('address');
$address->setValue('test adress');

//If you have more field sets in your collection for example count = 3 and you want this    
//value for all of them just iterate your field sets.

foreach($fieldsets as $fieldset){
    $fieldset->get('address')->setValue('test adress');
}
```

Comment: No element by the name of [address] found in form, the error in line:

$address = $fieldSets[0]->get('address');

Comment: do you have element in your collection of name 'address'? pls show us Companies\Form\AddressFieldset

Comment: I add 'The address Fieldset file' now in the original post

Comment: Your element with label address in field set `AddressFieldset ` has `name` of "name". Change it to "address" and check my code again.

Comment: This hacky solution does work, but it simply is the wrong approach :S This shouldn't be needed at all. But if it works, who am I to judge ;)

Comment: I know its hacky @sam i never would use it. But I don`t want to judge why Ahmad wants it. He has asked to setValue() on one of his field set elements and i just tried to help here. But I agree with you 100%

Answer (score 3):

You can use Form populateValues() instead of setValue() method to do this: http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.3/classes/Zend.Form.Form.html#populateValues

So in Your case you should put in your controller:

```
$form = new CompaniesForm();
$addresses = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'address field 1 name'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'address field 2 name'
    ),
);
$form->get('address')->populateValues($addresses);
```

You can generate the addresses array using data from your DB for example.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, it appears that some things are getting mixed up here. You try to manually assign Field-Values inside an `EditForm`. That's ... no good.

Imagine a simple Form

```
UserForm
   textInput ("name")
   textInput ("surname")
   numberInput ("age")
```

Now you want to edit a `User`. So you grab the Data from DB

```
//$userData = $db->get('userdata')...
$userData = array(
    'name'    => 'Peter',
    'surname' => 'Parker',
    'age'     => 23
);
```

To put the existing values into your form, all you have to do is to set the FORM into this data.

```
$form->setData($userData);
```

And that's all. In your case, obviously the data-structure is a little more different and more difficult. You'd have to have either a main Object that you could `$form->bind()` or your array that you set the forms data to using `$form->setData()` needs to be modified. In your case this would be:

```
$data = array(
    'id' => 1, // your objects id
    'name' => 'someName',
    'email' => 'foo@bar.baz',
    'address' => array(
        0 => array(
            'streetName'   => 'FooStreet',
            'streetNumber' => 42
        ),
        1 => array(
            'streetName'   => 'OofStreet',
            'streetNumber' => 24
        ),
    )
)
```

When you do `$form->setData($data)` using the above case, your form will be pre-filled with the data coming from the array. Naturally you'd have to get the data from the DB and not write an array manually.

Comment: I use $form->bind($companies); in other modules when there's no collection and no multiple table but i don't know how to use it here, is there is a full example tutorial for this case?

Comment: Your companies object needs to have a `getAddress()` function that returns an array of object that the `AddressFieldset` needs.

Comment: I write this

`code`
foreach ($addresses as $address) {
  $companies->address = $address;
}
`code`

Before $form->bind($companies); And it's add to the $companies but without the form read it.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to do this in a controller using getTargetElement() will return the element or fieldset assigned in the collection.

```
$fieldset = $form->get('parent_fieldset');
$collection = $fieldset->get('collection');
$collectionFieldset = $collection->getTargetElement();
$collectionFieldset->get('element')->setValue($value);
```