# How to decorate Elements of a Fieldset in a Collection in ZF2?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-form-element, zend-form-collection, zend-form-fieldset

In my current project I'm using nested `Zend\Form\Fieldset`s and [**`Zend\Form\Collection`s**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html), that provide an extremely comfortable way to map complex object structures to the form, in order to get a complete object (ready to be saved) from the form input.

To the problem: I have a `Fieldset` `FooFieldset` containing an `Element` `foo_element` with a `Label` "foo element" (code see below) and need to use this twice: 1. as a single `Fieldset`; 2. in a `Collection`. At the first place in the form I want its elements to be displayed; at the the second place I want to disable the labels (or maybe change them). (I also want to format it another way in the second case, but the most important thing now is the label.)

How to decorate `Zend\Form\Element`s of a `Zend\Form\Fieldset` in a `Zend\Form\Element\Collection` depending on the context?

---

**Code**

```
class FooFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->add([
            'type' => 'text',
            'name' => foo_element',
            'options' => ['label' => _('foo element')]
        ]);
    }
    public function getInputFilterSpecification() { ... }
}

class BarFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->add([
            'name' => 'foo',
            'type' => 'My\Form\Fieldset\Foo',
            'options' => []
        ]);
    }
    public function getInputFilterSpecification() { ... }
}

class BuzFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
        $this->add(
            [
                'name' => 'foos',
                'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
                'options' => [
                    'label' => _('multiple foos'),
                    'count' => 5,
                    'should_create_template' => true,
                    'template_placeholder' => '__placeholder__',
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'target_element' => [
                        'type' => 'Order\Form\Fieldset\Foo',
                    ],
                    'label_attributes' => [
                        'class' => 'col-md-12'
                    ]
                ]
            ]);
    public function getInputFilterSpecification() { ... }
}

echo $this->formRow($myForm->get('main_fieldset')->get('bar')->get('foo')->get('foo_element');
echo $this->formRow($myForm->get('main_fieldset')->get('buz')->get('foos');
```

---

**Workaround 1**

It would be possible to use another `Fieldset`, e.g. a sub-class of `FooFieldst` (sometnig like `FooFieldsetForUsingInCollection extends FooFieldst`) and adjust the `Label` (and other settings) there.

**Workaround 2**

It also would be possible to access the `Collection`'s `Element`s in the view script and manipulate them there (as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20218130/2019043) demonstrated). But I don't really like this solution, since then the `Fieldset` is defined at multiple places. And it also need further effort, if the number of the `Collection` elements is variable.

Comment: Is `main_fieldset` = `BuzFieldset`?

Comment: No, `Bar` and `Buz` are both Sub-`Fieldset`s of the `MainFieldset`. Sorry, it was a typo. Please see the corrected code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to reuse the 'foos' collection and the 'bar' element together in their own fieldset while keeping how it is currently created.

I would

- Move the collection element `foo` out of the `BuzFieldset::init` and into it's own *factory* (create the element and all it's options in the factory).
- Register it with the form element manager as and new service, lets call it `FooCollection`. This *element* is now reusable and can be called from the form element manager as `$fem->get('FooCollection')`.
- Replace removed `$fieldset->add('type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection')` with `$fieldset->add('type' => 'FooCollection')` in `BuzFieldset`.
- Repeat for `foo_element` with a new service name of `FooElement`.
- Then you need to create a new fieldset factory called `FooCollectionAndFooElementFieldsetFactory` this factory will return a new fieldset with both the `FooCollection` and `FooElement` attached.
- In the *factory* of `main_fieldset` decide if you need to attach `FooCollectionAndFooElementFieldsetFactory` or the existing `bar` or `baz` fieldsets.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Though, it seems a bit too complicated. I think, there is currently no Zend solution for this problem. But if I have to workaround it, I would use this way: 1. create a `FooForCollectionFieldsetFactory`; 2. manipulate the `FooFieldset` there; 3. add `'My\Form\Fieldset\FooForCollection' => 'My\Form\Fieldset\Factory\FooForCollectionFieldsetFactory'` to the `form_elements.factories` in the `module.config.php`; 4. set the `target_element.type` for the `Collection` to `'My\Form\Fieldset\FooForCollection'`.